# EF Core computed primary key property not updating

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1, computed-properties

I have a computed primary key in SQL Server configured like this in my entity:

```
        var e = builder.Entity<MyEntity>();

        e.ToTable("MyTable", "MySchema")
            .HasKey(k => k.Id);

        e.Property(k => k.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        e.Property(k => k.Id)
            .Metadata.BeforeSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;

        e.Ignore(i => i.PreviousId);
```

How can I get the property updated after saving changes in EF Core 2.1?

```
myEntity.RelatedProperty = 1;
_db.SaveChangesAsync();

// Here I want to have my updated Id
```

UPDATE:
This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [MySchema][MyTable](
    [Id]  AS (isnull((CONVERT([nvarchar],[RelatedProperty],(0))+'-')+CONVERT([nvarchar],[RelatedProperty2],(0)),'-')) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [RelatedProperty] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RelatedProperty2] [int] NOT NULL   
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not. Changing PK's are not supported. If you think this is a problem - wait until you start trying to use them in foreign key relationships.